# Aggregated result with multilevel map in apex

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, map, aggregateresult

I am trying to model aggregated data with the with bellow approach. I am Stuck in shaping up data like as shown bellow so that I can add it into my component. I tried with conditional logics to build data but wasn't working :( . Any help to construct my data would be appreciated. thanks.

```
List<AggregateResult> aggriRes = [ 
  SELECT 
    SUM(Qty_Invoiced__c)QtyInvoiced, 
    SUM(Total_Contribution_USD__c)TotalContributionUSD,  
    SUM(Total_Value_USD__c)TotalValueUSD,  
    CALENDAR_YEAR(Invoice_Date__c)InvoiceDate, 
    Product__r.Product_Center__c 
  FROM Billings__c 
  WHERE Invoice_Date__c >= LAST_N_YEARS:4 
    AND (Account__c=:recordId OR SF_Account_Number__c =:recordId OR Project_Owner_Account__c =:recordId) AND (Order_Status__c = 'Open' OR Order_Status__c = 'Closed') 
    GROUP BY CALENDAR_YEAR(Invoice_Date__c), Product__r.Product_Center__c ];

Map<string, Map<Integer,List<HistoryWrapper>>> resmap = new Map<string, Map<Integer,List<HistoryWrapper>>>();

for(AggregateResult res: aggriRes )
{ resmap.put(res.get('Product_Center__c'),  new Map<Integer,List<HistoryWrapper>>  {(Integer)res.get('QtyInvoiced') => (Double)res.get('QtyInvoiced') } );

//resmap.put(res.get('Product_Center__c'),  new Map<Integer,List<HistoryWrapper>>  {res.get('InvoiceDate'), (Double)res.get('QtyInvoiced') }  );
}
}
}
```

my data expectations are like this:

```
                  value of ProductCenter-1{
                            value of InvoiceDate-1 {
                            QtyInvoiced = ...;
                            TotalContributionUSD = ...;
                            TotalValueUSD = ...;
                                 }
                            value of InvoiceDate-2 {
                            QtyInvoiced = ...;
                            TotalContributionUSD = ...;
                            TotalValueUSD = ...;
                                 }
                 }
                 value of ProductCenter-2{
                            value of InvoiceDate-1 {
                            QtyInvoiced = ...;
                            TotalContributionUSD = ...;
                            TotalValueUSD = ...;
                                 }
                            value of InvoiceDate-2 {
                            QtyInvoiced = ...;
                            TotalContributionUSD = ...;
                            TotalValueUSD = ...;
                                 }
                 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably build a set of inner apex classes and serialize/deserialize the result into them.

However, you can do it this way - but you need to construct both maps carefully, checking if the key is there.

Like this:

```
Map<string, Map<Integer,List<HistoryWrapper>>> resmap = new Map<string, Map<Integer,List<HistoryWrapper>>>();

for(AggregateResult res: aggriRes ){ 
  String productCenter = res.get('Product__r.Product_Center__c');
  if (!resmap.containsKey(productCenter)){
    resmap.put(productCenter,  new Map<Integer,List<HistoryWrapper>>());
  }
  Map<Integer,List<HistoryWrapper>> currentProdMap = resmap.get(productCenter);
  
  String quantityInvoiced = res.get('QtyInvoiced');
  if (!currentProdMap.containsKey(quantityInvoiced)){
    currentProdMap.put(quantityInvoiced,  new List<HistoryWrapper>());
  }
  //currently you are only adding one thing to your history wrapper, but you may want more 
  //depends on your constructor
  currentProdMap.get(quantityInvoiced).add(new HistoryWrapper((Double)res.get('QtyInvoiced')));

}
```

Also, see I tidied up your query bit - see how much easier to read and debug it is?